# append data is not showing? HELP!

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

im trying to append data using jquery, but its only showing the status messages but not the button! although the button deos show on firebug?

```
$("form.follow-form").live('submit', function(e) { /* stop event */
    e.preventDefault(); /* "on request" */
    $(this).find('i').addClass('active'); /* send ajax request */
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_more.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("ul.statuses").append(html);
            $("form.follow-form").remove();
  // this is not full code ;)
```

this is ajax_more.php file:

```
$query= mysql_query($result) or die(mysql_error().$result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$dateTime = $row['dt'];

  //the append shows this

      echo formatUpdate($row['user_note'],$row['dt']);

   }
?>

// but not this form, it deos show on firebug only

<form class="follow-form" method="post" action="ajax_more.php">
    <input name="date" value="<?php echo $dateTime ?>" type="hidden">
         <button type="submit" value="Actions" class="btn follow" title="123456">
        <i></i><span>More</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On success of your ajax call, you are removing the form:

```
$("form.follow-form").remove();
```

Try commenting this line out and run the code, see if the form appears.

```
//$("form.follow-form").remove();
```